# How to download a json file from url

Tags: browser

I am solving mongodb tutorials from mongodb university. Their website has a link called "download homework". When I click on the link, nothing gets downloaded, instead the json file intended to be downloaded is displayed on a webpage with url like https://somepath.json.

My question is how to download a json file when you have the URL pointing to it?

Comment: Questions about general browser usage are not suited to Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on another Stack Exchange site. You don't mention which browser you are using, but most browsers offer the option to download and save via a right-click menu or by clicking while holding a key. Read your browser's help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, it depends on what operating system you're using.

**On Windows**

If you right click and press "save" (Alternatively use ctrl-s) and then chose the file format "json" when saving.

**On macOS**

You can do this in a few ways, I'd suggest using curl. You'd do this by opening the terminal and navigating to the directory you'd like to download the file to. Then enter the following:

```
curl https://somedomain.com/somepath.json > fileName.json
```

This will download the file in its original format.

Comment: On Mac OS apple silicon you will need:

"curl https://somedomain.com/somepath.json > somepath.json"

Answer (score 4):

In a Mac, the curl solution proposed above doesn't work if the url isn't public (on my side I got this permissions error: `unauthorized permission requested`.

So, here's an alternative that worked for me. Using the Chrome browser, go to the url with the json, then right click, then 'Inspect'. That brings up the Chrome devtools ui. From there go to 'Sources' and you will see the json file in the list. Then right click and you will be able to click 'Save as'. This will then download the file to wherever you want!

[image]

**UPDATE:** In case this method doens't work (I realise it doesn't work in all cases), then simply copy-paste the text of the json into a text editor, and save the file with the json extension.

Answer (score 2):

I believe when you are navigating to https://somepath.json, you see the json loaded on the page within your browser. What I've done in the past (on Windows and on Mac) is right click within the browser, and click "save as" which should allow you to save the data to a .json file on your machine.

The other alternative is using curl. A good looking tutorial if need-be is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrWQFj8WctA